# Quartz upgrade to 2.X

Tags: quartz-scheduler

We upgrade our quartz from 1.8.6 to 2.1.
It appears that some ddl are missing in the official site (http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/migration-guide).
The issue we encountered was that SCHED_TIME should be added to QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS table.
We found an issue about it which says that the site will be updated in version 2.2 ([quartz jira site](https://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/QTZ-387?jql=text%20~%20%22SCHED_TIME%22)).

Still, it seems that the issue was found in 2013 and the instruction in quartz site has not updated yet.
This missing fail the migration from 1.8.6 to 2.1
Has anyone encounter this issue as well?